# react-native-router-flux pass props to tabbar component

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

Hi i am trying to pass data to tabbar Scene using react-native-router-flux.
so i have three Scene
1: LOGIN
2: REGISTER
3: DASHBOARD

Once user is registered i am moving the user from register scene to dashboard scene. I am using firebase so once user is created i am getting a uid. i want to pass that uid as props to tabbar view.

Problem which i am facing is if i remove tabbar from my scene and pass data as `Actions.DASHBOARD({ uid: uid })` its working.

But its not working with tabbar.
https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/1230 
saw this error on github.

Also did some research on stakoverflow and github and found that i have to use `Actions.jump("SCENE_NAME", {uid: uid})` that is also not working.

if anyone have faced this kind of problem and if found the solution please help.

inside my App.js i have all the scenes declared like this. please let me know if i am making any mistake.

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Scene key="ROOT" style={styles.container}>
                    <Scene
                        key="tabbar"
                        tabs={true}
                        tabBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' }}
                        navTransparent
                    >
                        <Scene key="LOGIN" component={Login} title="Login Screen" />
                        <Scene
                            key="REGISTER"
                            component={Register}
                            title="Register Screen"
                            initial={true}
                        />
                        <Scene key="DASHBOARD" component={Dashboard} title="Dashboard Screen" />
                    </Scene>
                </Scene>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

> Inside Register.js i have a function which i am calling on a click.

```
// register.js
onRegisterClick = () => {
    const { email, fname, lname } = this.state;

    app.auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, 'qwertyuiop')
        .then(data => {
            const userId = data.user._user.uid;
            return userId;
        })
        .then(userId => {
            app.database()
                .ref('Users')
                .child(userId)
                .set({
                    email,
                    fname,
                    lname
                });
            return userId;
        })
        .then(userId => {
            Actions.jump('DASHBOARD', { uid: userId });

        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Cannot create user');
        });
};
```

Comment: Can you post how you structured your scenes?

Comment: @Murmeltier i have added the new code. Please have a look.